# QFileSystemModel disable QFileIconProvider

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4, qfilesystemmodel

From looking around I've seen that the QFileIconProvider in the QFileSysetmModel can considerably slow things down. In my particular case I don't need it at all, but I can't find out how to easily just disable/remove it without causing a crash. This is my first time playing around with the model/view framework so it is possible the answer is quite simple and I just missed it in the documentation... but right now I can only find instances of sub-classing it, but no examples of getting rid of it altogether.

Comment: What actual evidence do you have that the alleged performance issues will affect your application?

Comment: @ekhumoro Didn't benchmark it myself, just from what I saw on a few other SO posts (sorry, don't still have the link).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The task that consumes a lot of time in the `QFileIconProvider` is to provide the icon since it has to load a file, etc. So a workaround for your case is to return a null `QIcon`:

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

class EmptyIconProvider(QtGui.QFileIconProvider):
    def icon(self, _):
        return QtGui.QIcon()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    view = QtGui.QTreeView()
    model = QtGui.QFileSystemModel(view)
    model.setIconProvider(EmptyIconProvider())
    model.setRootPath(QtCore.QDir.currentPath())
    view.setModel(model)
    view.setRootIndex(model.index(QtCore.QDir.currentPath()))
    view.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: You know I had this idea, but wasn't quite sure how to implement it. Works perfectly! And in my purely un-scientific observational test cases, it's running much more quickly!